# Ta-lib : Indicators work with stock but not with cryptocurrency

Tags: python, pandas, yahoo-finance, quantitative-finance, ta-lib

I have a problem when using the Ta-lib library. I'm trying to find the RSI and the Bollinger Bands of BTC-USD. The problem is that when I try to find them for any cryptocurrencies, it gives no value (NaN). But when I try to find them for any stocks it works. When I display the data (Open Close High Low Volume) it works all the time (for cryptocurrencies and stocks). It gives me correctly :
[picture_0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wVm0.jpg)

But when I calculate the RSI and the BBANDS for cryptocurrencies it doesn't work.

Here is my code :

```
def get_indicators(data):

   
   # Get RSI
   data["rsi"] = talib.RSI(data["Close"], timeperiod=7)
   data["upper"], data["middle"], data["lower"] = talib.BBANDS(data["Close"], timeperiod=10, nbdevup=2, nbdevdn=2)
# pprint(upper)
# pprint(middle)
# pprint(lower)
   return data


df2 = get_indicators(df)

df2
```

When I run that, it gives me that, when my df is the data frame of a stock:
[picture_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzE4X.jpg)

When I run that, when my df is the data frame of cryptocurrency, it gives me :
[picture_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eq33R.jpg)

In the beginning, I thought that the problem was with the indicator, so I tried to replace RSI with ROC to see if it changes something.

So, I replace `data["rsi"] = talib.ROC(data["Close"], timeperiod=7)` with `data["roc"] = talib.ROC(data["Close"], timeperiod=7)` and this time it calcultated the ROC correctly for both stocks and cryptocurrencies. It gave me:

[picture_3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24a0y.jpg)

I don't understand where the problem is, it is possible to calculate RSI and Bollinger Bands for stocks but not for cryptocurrencies. Can someone please help me?

Comment: I don't know much about cryptocurrency, but what does 'crypto' mean here? Please tell me. As for the technical indicator you are looking for (BTC-USD), it is calculated correctly in my environment.

Comment: Oh sorry, by crypto I mean cryptocurrency. I'll edit my question. Well, I don't understand what is the problem... I'm doing it on Google Colab

Comment: @r-beginners hey thanks! The link does not allow me to access directly, so I made an access request.

Comment: @Sanosh Passoubaby Request accepted.

Comment: @r-beginners hey sorry I didn't receive any mail saying that the request is accepted. It is still refused for me...  Can you please create a link that can be seen by everyone? Then I can access it without your permission. I will copy your notebook and send you a confirmation message to delete your comment.

Comment: @r-beginners Thank you so much! You can delete your comment now ;)

Comment: Comment deleted as it seems to have been confirmed. I apologize for the time it took due to my inexperience.
Next, I will delete the files in the Collaboratory, so please comment when you are ready to delete them.

Comment: @r-beginners Don't be sorry, I must be sorry for wasting your time ;). I already copied it, you can delete him, no problem!

Answer (score 0):

The error is not with you but with the way that TAlib calculates the ROC. If you specify a time period of 10 then the first 10 results cannot be calculated because it doesn't have a value for 10 iterations back to compare. So it just fills them as `NaN`. Try changing the time period to test it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).